# Optimize UPDATE JOIN query in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, mysql5

I am running the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE A 
  join B 
    on A.b_id  = B.id 
   SET B.col1 = 'val1'
     , B.col2 = ''
     , B.col3 = 1
 where a.col4 = 'val4' 
   and b.col5 = 1234 
   and b.col6 = 1 
   and b.col7 = 'val7';
```

In table B, id is PRIMARY KEY of B, in table A. b_id is just a column in A supposed to have same value as id of table B.

My question is, is there any way to optimize the above query with/without (preferable) changing table definition ? Thanks.

Comment: When you ask for help with SQL query optimization, you should post the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` of each table referenced in the query, and the output of `EXPLAIN ...` for your SQL statement. Please don't make us guess at your columns and indexes in the tables. Help us to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    on A.b_id  = B.id 
   SET B ...
   WHERE
   and b.col5 = 1234 
   and b.col6 = 1 
   and b.col7 = 'val7';
```

I don't know whether it will start with `A` or `B`.  So, let me recommend indexes for each:

```
B:  INDEX(col5, col6, col7, id)
A:  INDEX(b_id)
A:  INDEX(col4, b_id)
```

Those will also help Ronnie's subquery approach.

If you have a new enough version, please provide `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...` both before and after adding these indexes.  (Old versions of MySQL don't have that command.)

Answer (score -1):

You use **SUBQUERY** to perform JOIN to reduce the number of rows involved to the JOIN.

Since you only update table **B**'s column , so you only put B at **UPDATE** clause. **INNER JOIN** was suggested to prevent some unwanted updates.

The enhancement shown as below:-

```
 UPDATE B SET B.col1 = 'val1', B.col2 = '', B.col3 = 1 
     FROM (SELECT b_id FROM A WHERE a.col4='val4') as tableA
     INNER JOIN B ON tableA.b_id  = B.id 
     WHERE b.col5=1234 AND b.col6=1 AND b.col7='val7';
```

Comment: I see no 'enhancement' here !?! :-(

Comment: Are you sure? the sub query before join should had some impact when the table "A" have huge data.

Comment: Well, in the first instance, your query would result in a syntax error.

Comment: Secondly, presupposing what improvements might be made to a query without looking at the underlying structure of its component tables is... well, decorum prevents me from saying.